# php foreach invalid argument

Tags: php, foreach

I'm building a video search engine and want to create a for everyone just like youtube does.The problem is i'm having trouble with php foreach().I get invalid supplied argument error.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$name=$row['Name'];
}
foreach($name as $key=>values) {
echo '<div id="block'><h1>'.$name.'</h1></div>';    
}?>
```

Thanks

Comment: That would be because `$name` is not *an array*.

Comment: `$name=$row['Name'];`.  You are setting `$name` to a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div id="block"><h1>'.$row['Name'].'</h1></div>';   
   }
?>
```

$name is not an array. also you don't want to use the foreach here. while loop is working there. so do the stuff like that. if you need foreach then $name is used as a array.

```
$name[] = $row['Name'];
```

Comment: Please ensure you include a written explanation of any solutions as well as a code sample :-)

Comment: so i should replace something with the $string?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) extension because it's deprecated, use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead.

Anyway, that's how I would do it :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'"); //be careful you might need to secure the $nemo var.

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) //fetch_assoc to have an associated array
{
    $name = $row['Name'];

    echo '<div id="block"><h1>'.$name.'</h1></div>'; //here you placed a ' instead of a "
    //Do the rest of your stuff here
}
```

Your datas are beeing parsed from the `mysql_query` within the `while`, you don't need to parse them again using `foreach` or whatever.

Another example for writing all names :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'");

echo '<div id="block"><h1>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    echo $row['Name'] . ',';

echo '</h1></div>';
```

Comment: You mean it's gonna create a block for every $name found?

Comment: Yes it would but you could write all names within the block too, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, you can just loop through the result set and print out $row['Name'] there.

```
<?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
      echo '<div id="block"><h1>'.$row['Name'].'</h1></div>';    
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach is used with arrays, but `$name` is string because you assign cell value to it.
to make it an array and add items to it, it should be like `$name[]=$row['Name'];`
now your code should become:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$name[]=$row['Name'];
}
foreach($name as $key=>values) {
    echo '<div id="block"><h1>'.$name.'</h1></div>';    
}
?>
```

Comment: unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/content/58/10512158/html/hom.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you give foeach() any parameter other than array ....
The first thing I that came to my mind after reading your question is that the parameters is not a valid array ... 
The proper code will be

```
     <?php
        $name = array(); // declare $name as array 
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM videos WHERE Name='$nemo'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
         $name[]=$row['Name'];
        // now even $name = $row['Name'] means $name[0] = 'value of $row['Name']'
        }
       // Now it will definately work
        foreach($name as $key=>values) 
        {
            echo '<div id="block'><h1>'.$name.'</h1></div>';    
        }
     ?>
```